# Filling null row values with last non-null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Consider the example table posted  below. What I need to do is to update the table, specifically the NULL values on each row with the "last" non-NULL values. For example, the NULL values on rows 3 and 4 should be updated with the values of row 2 of the same column, that is

```
2   007585102   2001 03 31   2001 04 12   2   154980   6300   154980   6300  
3   007585102   2001 03 31   2001 04 19   2   154980   6300   154980   6300  
4   007585102   2001 03 31   2001 04 26   2   154980   6300   154980   6300
```

and NULL values on rows 9 to 15 updated with the values of row 8 and so on.
I honestly have no idea how to do this and I will greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Sorry about the extremely poor formatting of the table but I can't post anything but plain text.

EXAMPLE TABLE

```
1    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 04 05   2    543660   22100   543660   22100  
2    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 04 12   2    154980   6300    154980    6300  
3    007585102       NULL     2001 04 19  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL  
4    007585102       NULL     2001 04 26  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL  
5    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 05 03   2    2726664  110840 2726664 110840  
6    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 05 10   2    836400   34000   836400   34000  
7    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 05 17   2    534804   21740   7634364  310340  
8    007585102   2001 03 31   2001 05 24   2    4920      200      4920       200  
9    007585102       NULL     2001 05 31   NULL     NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    
10   007585102       NULL     2001 06 07  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL  
11   007585102       NULL     2001 06 14  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL   
12   007585102       NULL     2001 06 21  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL   
13   007585102       NULL     2001 06 28  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL   
14   007585102       NULL     2001 07 05  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL  
15   007585102       NULL     2001 07 12  NULL      NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL  
16   007585102   2001 06 30   2001 07 19   2    2693301   118300   2693301   118300  
17   007585102   2001 06 30   2001 07 26   2    232220    10200    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explained this in details here:
https://koukia.ca/common-sql-problems-filling-null-values-with-preceding-non-null-values-ad538c9e62a6#.k0dxirgwu
here is the TSQL you need,

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM ImportedSales;

;With CTE
As
(
   SELECT ProductName
          , Id
          , COUNT(ProductName) OVER(ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As MyGroup
   FROM #Temp
),
GetProduct
AS
(
    SELECT [ProductName]
           , First_Value(ProductName) OVER(PARTITION BY MyGroup ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As UpdatedProductName
    FROM CTE
)

UPDATE GetProduct
Set ProductName = UpdatedProductName;

SELECT *
FROM #TemP;
```

Comment: How do I achieve the same result in SQL Server 2008 R2? as I understand the ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING clause was included from 2012 onwards.

Comment: You can use the CTE solution posted here: https://koukia.ca/common-sql-problems-filling-null-values-with-preceding-non-null-values-ad538c9e62a6#.k0dxirgwu

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, for that I'd suggest a recursive CTE.

```
drop table #temp
GO
select 
    *
into #temp
from (
    select 1 as id, '2001 03 31' as dat union all
    select 2, '2001 03 31' union all
    select 3, null union all
    select 4, null union all
    select 5, '2001 03 31' union all
    select 6, '2001 03 31' union all
    select 7, '2001 03 31' union all
    select 8, '2001 03 31' union all
    select 9, null union all
    select 10, null union all
    select 11, null union all
    select 12, null union all
    select 13, null union all
    select 14, null union all
    select 15, null union all
    select 16, '2001 06 30' union all
    select 17, '2001 06 30'
) x

update t
set
    t.dat = t2.dat
from #temp t
join (
    select 
        t1.id, max(t2.id) as maxid
    from #temp t1
    join #temp t2
        on t1.id>t2.id
        and t2.dat is not null 
        and t1.dat is null 
    group by 
        t1.id
) x
    on t.id=x.id
join #temp t2
    on t2.id=x.maxid

select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

In redshift, and I think other SQL flavors, you can combine `nvl()` and `lag()` functions, being sure to use the ignore nulls option when using `lag()`.

I adapted this from https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/ .

I'm going to the call the second date field in your example "date_field" since I didn't see a column header.

Let's assume you have a column called "row_number" on which you can correctly order your values.

Then the example using your above data would be like

```
select nvl(date_field,lag(date_field,1)) ignore nulls over ([partition by whatever] order by rownumber).
```

This should grab the nearest non-null value above in the column (which is ordered by whatever columns you specified), and replace the nulls until it hits a non-null value.

Ignore nulls is the key b/c otherwise you'll just grab the first non-null, then the next null, so that you only replace one row.

Comment: Hi I'm interested in your answer but is missing a parenthesis, can you check the spell?