# Replace nulls from previous or next values and add date of its price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to search through all values, find missing one and replace null values and add proper date to it for new value.

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 3/5/2020 | 40 |
| 5/5/2020 | null |
| 7/5/2020 | 30 |
| 30/5/2020 | null |
| 1/6/2020 | null |
| 3/6/2020 | null |
| 5/6/2020 | 55 |

| Date | Price | PriceDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/5/2020 | 40 | null |
| 5/5/2020 | 40 | 3/5/2020 |
| 7/5/2020 | 30 | null |
| 30/5/2020 | 30 | 7/5/2020 |
| 1/6/2020 | 55 | 5/6/2020 |
| 3/6/2020 | 55 | 5/6/2020 |
| 5/6/2020 | 55 | null |

Point is - for May I need to replace next values, for June I need to take value from 5th June and replace previous days.
In both cases, I need also add additional columns with date from values that I'm taking.

My problem is: How to get values from older days - in this case June and replace them and how to add additional to that date (PriceDate) column?

I've made also some changes, was able to get values that I wanted, but I wonder how to get proper dates to this one (see second table - as output):

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler

What I've done so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale (
    DatePrice DATE,
    Price FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO Sale (DatePrice, Price) VALUES
('2020-05-02', NULL),
('2020-05-03', 40.00),
('2020-05-05', NULL),
('2020-05-06', NULL),
('2020-05-07', 30.00),
('2020-05-30', NULL),
('2020-06-01', NULL),
('2020-06-03', NULL),
('2020-06-05', 55.00),
('2020-06-06', 60.00),
('2020-06-09', NULL),
('2020-07-02', 72.00),
('2020-07-04', NULL),
('2020-07-06', NULL),
('2020-07-07', NULL),
('2020-07-19', 80.00);


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FilledPrices') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FilledPrices;
SELECT
    DatePrice,
    Price,
    YEAR(DatePrice) AS Year,
    MONTH(DatePrice) AS Month,
    NULL AS FilledPrice 
INTO #FilledPrices
FROM Sale;


WITH FirstPrices AS (
    SELECT
        Year,
        Month,
        MIN(DatePrice) AS FirstDate
    FROM #FilledPrices
    WHERE Price IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Year, Month
)
UPDATE fp
SET fp.FilledPrice = s.Price
FROM #FilledPrices fp
INNER JOIN FirstPrices f ON fp.Year = f.Year AND fp.Month = f.Month
INNER JOIN Sale s ON s.DatePrice = f.FirstDate
WHERE fp.Price IS NULL AND fp.DatePrice <= f.FirstDate;


UPDATE fp
SET fp.FilledPrice = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Price
    FROM #FilledPrices
    WHERE Year = fp.Year AND Month = fp.Month AND DatePrice < fp.DatePrice AND Price IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY DatePrice DESC
)
FROM #FilledPrices fp
WHERE fp.Price IS NULL AND fp.FilledPrice IS NULL;


UPDATE #FilledPrices
SET FilledPrice = Price
WHERE Price IS NOT NULL;

SELECT
    DatePrice,
    COALESCE(FilledPrice, Price) AS Price
FROM #FilledPrices
ORDER BY DatePrice;
```

I'm using in this case temp table. First off - I'm searching empty values in specific month before first record with data. If there is this kind of situation, replace nulls with first met value. In second iteration I'm searching through all values and if null is found, then replace it with value from previous record. And this is working just fine, my results:

| DatePrice | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-05-02 | 40.0 |
| 2020-05-03 | 40.0 |
| 2020-05-05 | 40.0 |
| 2020-05-06 | 40.0 |
| 2020-05-07 | 30.0 |
| 2020-05-30 | 30.0 |
| 2020-06-01 | 55.0 |
| 2020-06-03 | 55.0 |
| 2020-06-05 | 55.0 |
| 2020-06-06 | 60.0 |
| 2020-06-09 | 60.0 |
| 2020-07-02 | 72.0 |
| 2020-07-04 | 72.0 |
| 2020-07-06 | 72.0 |
| 2020-07-07 | 72.0 |
| 2020-07-19 | 80.0 |

Last thing I need to do is to create additional table with PriceDate and fill dates for records that had nulls with the date from records that we've taken values, for records that has not change, leave null value for date - see example as second table in post as a example.

Comment: So what research did you do? When I search the first thing I found is this, which appears to mostly solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203750/filling-null-row-values-with-last-non-null-values-sql-table

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, some values are empty after a specific rows - for example for May. As you can see, I must look also at date or specific month. For June - i need to look for previous rows. Idea is to search for values that are before or after specific row and also look at date. In June I need to take previous rows. For May, rows after a specific value placed.
Ive tried to look at other results over here, but couldnt find similar problem to mine. Also, in this case, I need to remember to fill proper date (date from row with the price) and add it for missing values in additional column

Comment: Updated with what i have, but not sure how get dates and get proper values in June

Comment: Ps. Thank you for editing, still learning using stackoverflow :(

Comment: Why there is a different logic for month of May and June. For May you use previous Price but for June, you use next. How are you going to determine which logic to use

Comment: You're not supposed to randomly take prices from back and forth, so this logic of yours looks very strange to me

Comment: @DaleK, regarding ('2020-05-06', NULL) - ive checked that, trying to fix it.
Regarding second question - no, but but probably it would be even better to add unique id's there.

Comment: @Squirrel - its an random sample, various scenarious might happend within one or different months

Comment: @DaleK, updated query with example results. For this example I've added few values to see how this gonna work with bigger sample. So far it looks promising, but dunno how we can add additional column with dates and logic for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by finding the *maximum* date with a price *before* the current row - for all cases where an earlier record exists within the current month.

And then to handle the case when an earlier record with a price within the month doesn't exist, you find the *minimum* date with a price *after* the current row.

Normally you would use the ID column for this, but so long as the date is unique it will work.

Then for a row with a null price, if an earlier price exists, join that on, and if not then join on the later date.

By joining on the original row you have access to all the columns to do whatever you wish.

Note I added an extra row to the sample data to demonstrate.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sale (
    DatePrice DATE,
    Price DECIMAL(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Sale (DatePrice, Price)
VALUES
('2020-05-03', 40.00),
('2020-05-05', NULL),
('2020-05-06', NULL),
('2020-05-07', 30.00),
('2020-05-30', NULL),
('2020-06-01', NULL),
('2020-06-03', NULL),
('2020-06-05', 55.00);

WITH SalesWithMonth AS (
    SELECT
        DatePrice
        , Price
        -- Find the closest row with a price prior to this row
        , MAX(CASE WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN DatePrice END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY YEAR(DatePrice), MONTH(DatePrice)
            ORDER BY DatePrice
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) MaxDatePrice
        -- Find the closest row with a price after this row
        , MIN(CASE WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN DatePrice END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY YEAR(DatePrice), MONTH(DatePrice)
            ORDER BY DatePrice
            ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
        ) MinDatePrice
    FROM dbo.Sale
)
SELECT
    swm.DatePrice [Date]
    , coalesce(s.Price, swm.Price) Price
    , s.DatePrice PriceDate
FROM SalesWithMonth swm
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sale s
    ON s.DatePrice = CASE WHEN swm.Price IS NULL THEN COALESCE(MaxDatePrice, MinDatePrice) END
ORDER BY swm.DatePrice;
```

Returns:

| Date | Price | PriceDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-03 | 40.00 | NULL |
| 2020-05-05 | 40.00 | 2020-05-03 |
| 2020-05-06 | 40.00 | 2020-05-03 |
| 2020-05-07 | 30.00 | NULL |
| 2020-05-30 | 30.00 | 2020-05-07 |
| 2020-06-01 | 55.00 | 2020-06-05 |
| 2020-06-03 | 55.00 | 2020-06-05 |
| 2020-06-05 | 55.00 | NULL |

Note: Don't, ever, use `FLOAT` for money, you will be dealing with rounding errors from then on. Use a `DECIMAL`.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VObpuszI)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with that. Also code looks less complicated and more clear than mine. 

Thank you once again!